# Postgis make error on MacOS

Tags: postgis, sfcgal

I could compile it with the following command on Macbook mavericks.

```
./configure --with-sfcgal=/usr/local/Cellar/sfcgal/1.0.4/bin
```

Then, I receive following results along with lists:

> PostGIS is now configured for x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0

make gives an error:

> Can't fetch local revision (neither .svn nor .git found)
>   Not updating existing rev file at 12547
>   for s in liblwgeom libpgcommon postgis regress raster topology loader utils extentions; do \
>   ...
>   "sfcgal_triangulated_surface_triangle_n", referenced from:
>   _SFCGAL2LWGEOM in liblwgeoma(lwgeom_sfcgal.o)
>   "sfcgal_version", referenced from:
>   _lwgeom_sfcgal_version in liblwgeom.a(lwgeom_sfcgal.o)
>   (may be you meant: _lwgeom_sfcgal_version, _pg_finfo_postgis_sfcgal_version, _postgis_sfcgal_version )
>   ld: symbold(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make[1]: *** [postgis2.1.so] Error 1
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

Postgresql was installed using brew. I uninstalled Postgis brew installation in order to have SFCGAL functions compiled with Postgis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andre,

This is a bug in our make that it doesn't give a warning that you are pointing at an invalid path for sfcgal.  The --with-sfcgal should be the path to the sfcgal-config file.